# How to make a special flex in 2x2

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am triying to make a "special" responsive flex

I have this demo;

https://codepen.io/josemb94/pen/eYYdZea

In normal mode works ok(1);

```
-----------------
-  bla  -  ble  -
-  bla  -  ble  -
-  bla  -       -
-  bla  -       -
-----------------
-  two  - three -
-----------------
```

or can be (and works ok) (2);

```
-----------------
-  bla  -  ble  -
-       -  ble  -
-       -  ble  -
-       -  ble  -
-----------------
-  two  - three -
-----------------
```

In responsive mode (1)want that flex by columns and remove empty spaces

```
---------
-  bla  -
-  bla  -
-  bla  -
-  bla  -
---------
---------
-  two  -
---------
---------
- blee  -
- blee  -
---------
---------
- three -
---------
```

Responsive mode (2)want that flex by columns and remove empty spaces

```
---------
-  bla  -
-  bla  -
---------
---------
-  two  -
---------
---------
- blee  -
- blee  -
- blee  -
- blee  -
---------
---------
- thee  -
---------
```

"two" and "three" only contains 1 line. so same height.

But "bla" and "ble" could be different height.

In normal mode I want "two" and "three" aligned

In responsive mode I want "bla","two","ble","three" alignt without empty spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure I understand what you need, but I guess you're looking for this maybe:

**UPDATED**

HTML

```
<div class="grid2x2">
  <div class="box box1">bla<br/>bla<br/>bla<br/>bla</div>
   <div class="box box3">two</div>
  <div class="box box2">ble<br/>ble</div>
  <div class="box box4">three</div>
</div>
```

Styles

```
html, body {
  min-height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
}
.grid2x2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.grid2x2 > div {
  display: flex; 
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 40px);  
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.grid2x2 > div > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box { margin: 1px; }
.box1 { background-color: red; order: 1; }
.box2 { background-color: orange; order: 2; }
.box3 { background-color: purple; order: 3; }
.box4 { background-color: grey; order: 4; }

@media (max-width: 800px) { /* Use your own breakpoint here, doesn't have to be 800 */
  .grid2x2,
  .grid2x2 > div {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Paste this to your stylesheet an try resizing your window under 800px for the result.

Comment: Oh, ok, give me a second.

Comment: Check it out now, I reaordered the elements in the HTML and assign them a different `order` with flexbox.